# Don´t open .cube file in excel

Tags: excel, sharepoint, ssas, pivot-table

I have the following problem:

I have a process in SSIS and it generates `.cube` files and saves the files in Sharepoint folders.

I have users that open the files in excel. Some can see the data in the files and other can not see anything.

There is one user who opens the file on a computer on the company network and can not see the data in the `.cube` ​​file, but if the same user opens the same file on a personal computer the user can see the data in the file.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities here. First off, Excel has something called Trusted Locations. If a file is on a network share, you may need to add that share as a Trusted Location. Check the Excel backstage (or look for a video on Youtube about Trusted Locations) for more info.

Secondly, once the file is downloaded, do the properties of the file show the 'Unblock' button? They shouldn't for a typical intranet setup but there could be something unusual about your particular environment.